# Mercurial Branching Oddity

Tags: mercurial, branch

I'm trying to understand why the below is occuring:

[alt text http://img185.imageshack.us/img185/8301/capturexj.png](http://img185.imageshack.us/img185/8301/capturexj.png)

It appears that I have started another branch, but it has no name, and I do not remember creating a new branch.  Why did this new head(branch) get created?  How do I keep it from happening?

Comment: that's an anonymous branch, I really recommand reading http://stevelosh.com/blog/entry/2009/8/30/a-guide-to-branching-in-mercurial/

Comment: and it's normal to have it, for example when you pull from someone, you often end up with multiple branches that you need to merge. that's the bases of DVCS.

Comment: @tonfa: +1 I didn't consider pulling new heads from another repository (the OP's wording gave me the impression that it wasn't the case here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will happen if you update your working directory to an earlier revision and start making changes from there.  After the "fix broken link" commit, you did a `hg update` that brought you back to the "secondary address update" revision.

It's easily fixed by first making sure that your working directory is at the tip then `hg merge -r fix_broken_link`